# What is the next ROS distribution?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, the most recent distribution is Melodic. In keeping with the release schedule, a new version should come out in about a month. Has any information about the next distribution been released? I can't find so much as a name, much less potential changes or a release date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321483/what-is-the-next-ros-distribution?/) by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2019-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Discussion and updates about upcoming ROS releases happens on the ROS discourse server.

The next ROS release will be Noetic Ninjemys: https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-melodic-morenia-release/4871 (name announced as part of the Melodic release announcement).

It looks like there has been some discussion around planning the Noetic release, but it does not look very active: https://discourse.ros.org/t/planning-future-ros-1-distribution-s/6538 . I think most of OSRF's energy is focused on ROS2 at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) on 2019-04-21**:
A key part in this answers is linked to from the Noetic discussion: https://discourse.ros.org/t/proposed-changes-to-the-ros-releases/4736. Specifically, the decision to only make ROS releases on Ubuntu LTS releases was made, so Noetic will be on the next Ubuntu LTS, 20.04.